# Show Empty state in Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I want to show the empty state in my aura component. But in the slds code example there is a polyline tag that is not being identified by VScode. How should I implement this?
I am trying "One Call to Action - Button Brand" from the illustration.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/empty-state/#Illustration
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/illustration/#Using-Empty-States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to achieve this with the below code.

```
  <div class="slds-illustration slds-illustration_small" aria-hidden="true">
                <img src="/img/chatter/OpenRoad.svg" class="slds-illustration__svg" alt=""/>
                <div class="slds-text-longform">
                    <h2>Your Text.</h2>
                </div>
    </div>
```